Movie where butler walks down the wall and shouts at woman
A long time ago I saw this scene of a movie, that I would like to find again.
It is some sort of comedy, or at least contains comedic surreal elements. I would guess the film is from somewhere between 1950s - 1970s, it's in color.
The scene I remember is set indoors, possibly in some sort of mansion. A woman lies in a bed, we see her from the side and we see the wall behind her. Then a butler in typical butler-tuxedo outfit walks down the wall (yes, that means gravity works kind of sideways for him) holding a little tray with a glass of champagne on it. He comes to a hold when his face is kind of close to the woman's face and then shouts into her face: "CHAMPAGNE, MISS?".
(I actually saw the german dubbed version, where he literally shouted "Champagner, Miss?", but I guess, it would simply translate to "Champagne, Miss?")
So, me and my brother were both cracking up, but this is the only scene that I can remember.
The film was shown on New Year's morning on TV so maybe it is related to New Year's?
Does anyone know this film? Would be great!

Come to think of it, it could of course also have been a german film to begin with (so it would have not been dubbed), but I think that's unlikely.

If it was a German film (clip?), and it was shown around New Year's, it could be any of the old TV comedians like Diether Krebs (with the show https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sketchup_(Comedy)).

My first thought is Dinner For One which is traditionally shown on German TV on New Year's Eve.
However, a few points don't fit. There is no "sideways gravity", the woman is not in bed, and it's usually black and white (although there is a post-processed coloured version). Also, as far as I'm aware it is not dubbed on German TV.
Does these ring any bells?







No, that's not it.
As a German, I am definitely familiar with Dinner for One. ;)

New Year + butler + German TV does suggest an influence perhaps?
